# How to compare using HIbernate criteria on a string column treating it as a long column

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am working on a web project written in java that uses Hibernate for data access from a oracle database.

I have a column name `serial` in my database which is defined as `VARCHAR(12)` even though it contains only values that can be cast into `long`. My intention is get all serials (treating them as numbers) between numbers `fromNo` and `toNo`. I cannot use `Restrictions.between` because the `serial` column is not a number in DB. It is defined as `String` in the associated object as well. Right now I achieve the requirement (in an ugly way) by converting the number range to a list of strings and do a `Restricitons.in` on the column.

```
long fromNO = 10;
long toNo = 100;
List<String> listNos = null;
for (long k = fromNo; k <=toNO; k++) {
    listNos.add(k.toString());
}

Criteria criteria = getMyHibernateSession().createCriteria(MyObject.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in('serialNo',listNos));
List<MyObject> results = criteria.list();
```

Though I get the desired results, the problem happens when the `toNo` is not defined by the user and the tool need to get all the `serial` from `fromNo`

My question is how can write a hibernate criteria where I can overcome all this problem, by specifying Criteria to treat `serial` column as `long`  and not `String`? (Some sort of casting process may be?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new 'long' field in your entity annotated as

```
    @Formula("cast(serialNo as NUMBER(10,0))")
    private int lSerialNo;
```

Then use the new field `lSerialNo` in your `Restrictions`

Comment: How does this deal with null values?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use Restrictions.between. Try to parse the integer to string

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.between('serialNo',String.valueOf(listNosFrom),String.valueOf(listNosTo)));
```